# Upload Attachment using Knockout.js and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, knockout.js

I'm having trouble getting attachments to save with my MVC 4 vb website. I am able to get a file that is a `media-type` file to send with an AJAX call to my controller, but I don't know how to use that file type to save or be converted to `HttpPostedFileBase`.

The error I'm receiving when uploading a .docx is:

```
"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'HttpPostedFileBase' from content with media type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'."
```

Here is a snippet of my html code:

```
<input id="files" name="files" class="input-file" type="file" data-bind="file: imageFile, fileObjectURL: imageObjectURL, fileBinaryData: imageBinary">
```

Here's my ko.bindinghandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.file = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).change(function () {
            var file = this.files[0];
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                valueAccessor()(file);
            }
        });
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var file = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var bindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if (bindings.fileObjectURL && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileObjectURL)) {
            var oldUrl = bindings.fileObjectURL();
            if (oldUrl) {
                windowURL.revokeObjectURL(oldUrl);
            }
            bindings.fileObjectURL(file && windowURL.createObjectURL(file));
        }

        if (bindings.fileBinaryData && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileBinaryData)) {
            if (!file) {
                bindings.fileBinaryData(null);
            } else {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    bindings.fileBinaryData(e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the AJAX call:

```
var fileData = monthView.imageFile();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/api/Upload/FileUpload",
    data: fileData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        imageFile(getNameFromPath(monthView.imageFile()));
    },
});
```

Finally here is the controller to handle the ajax call:

```
<System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost>
Public Function FileUpload(ByVal file As HttpPostedFileBase) As Boolean
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim pathName As String

    If file.ContentLength > 0 Then
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
        pathName = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName)
        file.SaveAs(pathName)
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the backend, but you might want to try creating a FileData() object, then .append('file', monthView.imageFile()):

```
var fileData = new FileData();
fileData.append('file', monthView.imageFile());
```

This seems to be the HTML5 standard for an ajax call with custom data.

Don
have a great day